# ¿Como obtengo el valor de una variable dentro del tag option de un select en jsp?

Tags: jsp

Cuando utilizo:

```
<div>
    <label class="control-label" for="nroOrden">Nro. Pedido:</label>
    <div>
        <form:input class="form-control" id="nroOrden" path="pedidos[${i}].nroOrdenPedido.nroOrden" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Visualizo el valor 1818

El problema es que cuando tengo un combo de nro de Orden y quiero que este seleccionado por ejemplo en este caso el 1818

```
<div>
    <label for="nroOrden2">Nro. Pedido:</label>
    <div>
        <select class="form-control" id="nroOrden2">
            <option class="form-control" value="0" selected="selected">Seleccione Nro. Orden</option>
            <c:forEach items="${nroOrdenList}" var="nroOrdenPedido">
                <option class="form-control" value="${nroOrdenPedido.id}" ${nroOrdenPedido.nroOrden == "1818" ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>${nroOrdenPedido.nroOrden}/option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

He probado con

```
<input type="hidden" name="np" value="pedidos[${i.index}].nroOrdenPedido.nroOrden" />

<form:hidden value="pedidos[${i.index}].nroOrdenPedido.nroOrden" name="np2" />
```

pero no he tenido exito con ninguno de los casos al reemplazar el "1818" por los name para que sea generico a cualquier nro de orden

Comment: quieres que por defecto aparezca el valor que trae de la base de datos? y no la primera opcion que es seleccione?

Comment: Desde otra pagina envío el nro de Pedido (en este caso el 1818, pero puede ser otro, con el tag form:input lo obtengo bien) y en la pagina actual cargo un combo con todos los pedidos y quiero que este seleccionado en este caso el 1818.

Comment: y como recibirias esa variable en la pagina es decir con que nombre?

Comment: estas usando jquery?

Comment: En el form:input obtengo por ejemplo el 1818 con pedidos[${i}].nroOrdenPedido.nroOrden y en la misma pagina no puedo obtener ese valor dentro de value del tag option. Quise darle un nombre con: <input type="hidden" y con <form:hidden pero no pude. Si uso Jquery

Comment: si estás usando elementos `<form:...>` podrías también usar el `<form:select path="...">` y se rellenará con el que venga en el formulario previamente rellenado

Comment: Perfecto, me funciono con el form_select     `<form:select class="form-control" id="nroOrden" path="pedidos[${i.index}].nroOrdenPedido.nroOrden">
        <form:option value="0" label="Seleccione Nro. Orden "" />
        <form:options items="${nroOrdenList}" itemValue="nroOrden" itemLabel="nroOrden" />
       </form:select>`